# Bonita BPM and Process Maker Bypass bundled server and Deploy business process in a third party portal

Tags: business-process-management

I have two identical processes done respectively with Processmaker and Bonita BPM.
Now i need to deploy them in my portal. i dont want to use the portal delivered inside the studio(bundled server) . Im new to business process management.

thanks

Comment: Sorry but your question is very general, that makes it hard to post a good answer. What portal do you want to deploy the processes to?

Comment: i have my own intranet. i want to deploy the process inside it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The processes you designed are made to run on a dedicated BPM server. It is not possible to deploy them directly to a webserver or some custom portal. If you want to integrate the processes in your intranet portal, that is absolutely possible, with BonitaBPM and with ProcessMaker. However, you will need to install the BonitaBPM server or ProcessMaker server and then integrate that server with your intranet portal.

AFAIK this is true for all BPM (proprietary and open source) solutions on the market, however my experience is mainly with BonitaBPM and ProcessMaker.

Comment: thanks very much for your prompt answer.  what i didnt understood is HOW TO INSTALL the PROCESS MAKER SERVER since i have preference for this environment as i develop in php.   and how to link it to my portal wich is using Apache/mysql.   Sorry but im little disoriented

Comment: Are you using ProcessMaker 2 or ProcessMaker 3?

Comment: If you see that the answer is too large for the context. Please suppose that we have a BPMN editor and an intranet  portal . how to inject the process in the portal?....Quick solution....simple tools....THANKS in advance

Comment: There are currently only instruction for setting up ProcessMaker 3 on a Linux server: http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/3.0/ProcessMaker_Generic_Installation

Comment: but i have it installed on win 7

Comment: That is your client installation. The processes produced on your client are server agnostic. A Windows Server instalaltion is something differetn.. If you want to install in Windows Server, that's absolutely possible, but you have to hire some consultancy or install BonitaBPM with the installation instructions.

Comment: Please  What i dont want is to have a portal under license with logo etc...so im looking for the best way to use a BPMN editor , build my processes, inject them to the my customized intranet ive developed. thats all.        UP TO NOW i found  YAOQIANG BPMN editor. im stopped here. i dont know where to find an engine to interpret and deploy the generated process . thats why im trying processmaker

Comment: Sorry but the only way to make that happen is with heavy customization to the BPM Engine. It's just a different beast than a portal.

Comment: You can find installation about how to install Bonita BPM server in the official [documentation](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/tomcat-bundle-2). If you want to change the logo / style, edit the web application resources (replace Bonita logo with your own and edit css files). You can embed Bonita BPM forms in your application using iframe or create your forms in PHP and use REST API to instantiate and execute processes.